# Windows swipe feature

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

Is there a way to disable the swipe left and/or right feature which changes the magnification of the view in Windows 8 or 10?

When I want to select a phrase or line of text, the magnification changes just because I am swiping right or left. This is very annoying. If I want the magnification to change I only want to do that in the view menu on purpose.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior on convertible notebook/tablet device with touchscreen. Only pinching changes the magnification, not swiping. Could you please [edit] your question and add steps to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a cursor properties. Please one your notification panel and check for mouse drivers options and settings. I have resolved mine by changing `Synaptics` settings.